# Why does the StackExchange Android app not go back to last page?

Tags: bug, stack-exchange, android-app

I use the StackExchange app on my Android device and whenever I choose to display questions by a tag then go on to view a specific question from that tag I find out that whenever I press the back button from the question which I'm on it takes me to the tags page and I think this should not be.

When I click back from the question I'm on it should take me back to the list of questions that I was shown when I choose a tag.

I should only get back to the "tag page" when I click back button from the results page(results of questions that are under the tag I chose at first).

I wanna know if this happens with just me or its a bug that needs to be fixed.